# Wife's Windows 8.1 notebook won't connect to wireless network when my computer is connected at the same time

Tags: wireless-networking, router, windows-8.1, dd-wrt

My wife's Windows 8.1 ([Dell Vostro 3450](http://www.dell.com/support/home/br/pt/brdhs1/product-support/servicetag/3BFFSR1/drivers?s=BSD)) notebook won't connect to our home network whenever my notebook is connected to it. It works fine whenever mine is not on. My router is a [Netgear N600 (WNDR3700)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002HWRJY4) with the latest stock firmware. All other devices (2 iPads and 2 iPhones) are working fine.

It says it "can't connect to the network". Digging on the event viewer I can see an entry under DeviceSetupManager source saying "Metadata staging failed, result={0C845880-00D2-1000-9F61-78ABBBA90644} for container '0x80072EFD'" and lots of DNS queries failling after that entry.

I already tried:

- Assigned static IP based on MAC address both for my notebook and hers
- Switching wireless channels
- Disconnecting(forgetting)/Reconnecting to the network
- Uninstalling/Installing drivers - Tried old and new ones
- Checking the option to prevent Windows from disable the wireless device to save power
- Changed the network name and password

I also looked on the routers log, but couldn't find anything.
Any ideas on what it might be before I start rebuilding the network using OpenWRT or DD-WRT?

Comment: Did you already reset the router? And are all devices configured for DHCP?

Comment: Try this: it's not exactly your problem but it may be worth trying out. Type in the search "device installation" > Click on "Change device installation settings" 

  Click on "No let me choose what to do" > choose the option "Never install driver software from Windows Update" and make sure that "Automatically get the device app and info provided by your device manufacture" is UNCHECKED. I think you'll need to restart it afterwards.

Comment: @Peter I already reset the router and everything is set to DHCP. You just made me remember that I also tried setting static IPs on our computers to avoid any kind of conflicts.

Comment: That's a fix for a "Metadata staging failed" error that I found online. Seemingly unrelated to your situation but you never know. Here's the original URL http://www.eightforums.com/bsod-crashes-debugging/53670-continues-errors-startup-metadata-staging-failed.html - Post#8 has this fix. I'd confirm that all the devices are operating on the same wireless mode and using the same encryption. Perhaps the router is falling back to a mode that your wife's laptop doesn't recognise?

Comment: What does your Router access logs say? Does it see the connection attempts?

Comment: You say you have DNS queries failing, can you just not resolve names? Can you open a command prompt and `ping 8.8.8.8`, if you can, you have a nameserver issue.

Comment: Sounds like the attempt at static IP's is your problem, perhaps it wasn't undone.  You should be able to confirm this by opening a command window on each while it's connected and typing ipconfig /all

Comment: What "IP based on MAC address" means? What IPs do you use?

Comment: Do this happens only with your wife's notebook? Or, is any other device blocked when you connect or do any device block your wife's, or even your notebook?